# List of self-defined class

Tags: c#

Hi I have a question about how to List.

I am trying to define a list by

```
List<periodrecord> pl=new List<periodrecord>(4);
```

Then I wish to add items to the list via a for loop

When I did this:

```
for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                periodrecord pr = new periodrecord();

                /*some random lines*/

                pl.Add(pr);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {  break; }
        }
```

My question is: The address of pr declared in each loop will be stored by the list. But since the pr variable itself ceases to be used by the program, will these locations be regarded as empty and somehow be overwritten? Thanks.

Considering the answer, there are still some doubts, my full codes are as follows:

```
   List<periodrecord> pl=new List<periodrecord>(4);
   for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                periodrecord pr = new periodrecord();
                record2 = sr.ReadLine();

                SNorPartCode = record1.Split('&')[0];
                phototype = int.Parse(record1.Split('&')[1]);
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                time = record1.Split('&')[2];
                pr.start = DateTime.Parse(time,provider);
                pr.SNorPartCode = SNorPartCode;
                pr.phototype = phototype;
                if (record2 != null)
                {
                    pr.end = DateTime.Parse(record2.Split('&')[2], provider);
                }
                else
                {
                    pr.end = DateTime.MaxValue;

                }
                pl.Add(pr);
                record1 = record2;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {  break; }
        }
```

When I took the line :
    periodrecord pr = new periodrecord();

out from the for loop, the lines

```
pr.start=...
pr.end=....
```

altered all the items in the list.

Comment: I dont understand your question?. can u clarify a little more

Answer (score 16):

> The address of pr declared in each loop will be stored by the list.

No, it won't. The *value* of the `pr` variable at the point at which `Add` is called will be stored in the list. That value is a reference - a reference to the new object you've created.

It's important to understand that the value of a variable in C# is *never* an object. It's always either a value type value, or a reference. Once you get your head round that - and start being very clear about the differences between variables, their values, references, and objects - a lot of things (parameter passing, assignment, garbage collection etc) become much clearer.

For example, consider:

```
Button x = new Button();
Button y = x;
```

There's only one *object* here - the `Button` created on the first line. There are two *variables* (`x` and `y`) and after the second line they both have the same value (a reference to that object) because of the assignment. They're still independent variables though (assigning a new value to `x` won't change `y`). Think about how that is applied to your example - you're calling `pl.Add(pr)` which just passes the *value* of `pr` to the `Add` method. After that, the `pr` variable is *completely irrelevant* as far as the list is concerned. So you could have:

```
pl.Add(pr);
pr = null;
```

and the second line wouldn't affect the list at all.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I need to digest it a bit. I guess simply thought List the same as an array but with no pre-defined size.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaboration. It has become much clearer now.

Comment: @JuntingZhu: Arrays behave in the same way in terms of storing references. So if you had an array and used `array[0] = pr;` that would still just store the current *value* of `pr`.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, after reading your further explanation, there are some other confusions coming up. Could you look at it for a bit? Thank you!

Comment: If you take the declaration out of the loop, you'll add a reference to the same item to the list over and over again, changing the properties of that single item in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Great answer above (of course, by Jon Skeet - I can't compete with it). But it sounds to me like your basic question is about how memory is managed in C#.  Memory is [managed automatically in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691138%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), the garbage collector automatically takes care of freeing up references to objects sometime after they go out of scope - i.e. in each iteration of the for loop in the case of the object `pr`.  However, the garbage collector will still know that the reference is still in use by the list, therefore it would never deallocate that until sometime after the list itself goes out of scope.

Regarding the updated question: when pr is inside the loop, you are adding to the list the value of pr which is a reference to that object. Every time you hit the loop, that will be a different reference as you are creating a new object. However, when pr is outside of the loop, every time you add to the list you would be adding to the list the value of pr (which is the reference), only this time the value is the same regardless of the iteration. So now every item on your list contains a reference to the same object, and every single item will reflect any changes to that reference. If you change the item at index 5, or 17, or 97, or any other index in the list, all items *as well as pr itself* will be modified since the value of all of these is the same object reference.